# ImportError: cannot import name 'PrintTable' in Python 3.5.1 by pyenv

Tags: python, pyenv

I installed pyenv to manage different versions of Python, and use `pip install printtable` to download and install `printtable`.

But when I import this module in interactive shell, it doesn't work and shows `ImportError`.

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
  2.7.11
* 3.5.1 (set by /Users/apple/.pyenv/version)
$ pip list
  pip (8.0.0)
  printtable (1.2)
  setuptools (18.2)
$ python
  Python 3.5.1 (default, Jan 21 2016, 12:50:43)
  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)] on darwin
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> import printtable
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/printtable/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  from printtable import PrintTable
  ImportError: cannot import name 'PrintTable'
```

How can I manage the modules in pyenv?

PS. I'm following the book `Automate the boring stuff` step by step. The `printtable` part is in the end of Chapter 6.

Visit: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter6/

Comment: Try to do a `pip3 install printtable` , maybe that'll work. Pip most probably installed the library for python2.x

Comment: `pip --version` tells what python version pip is installing packages to.

Comment: Yes, OP do that. Although OSX most probably has python2.x as default, so pip also might point to that python.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did `pip3 install printtable` and it showd `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): printtable in ./.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages`  Then I tried `pip --version`, the result was `pip 8.0.0 from /Users/apple/.pyenv/versions/3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)`, everthing seemed to be OK. I got really confused...

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded *printtable* with

```
pip3 install --download /tmp printtable
```

and inspected the contentents of *printtable-1.2.tar.gz*. In *printtable/printtable.py* there is code like

```
def  printTable(self,line_num=0):
....
    print self.StrTable
```

indicating that this package is not python 3 compatible.

It may be possible to install this module by

```
tar xfv printtable-1.2.tar.gz
cd printtable-1.2/
2to3-3.5 --write printtable/*.py tests/*.py
python3.5 setup.py build
python3.5 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re not doing anything wrong; the printtable module is simply written in a way that’s entirely incompatible with Python 3.

Since you’re already using pyenv, and according to the output of `pyenv versions` you already have Python 2.7.11 installed, you can simply install printtable for that Python interpreter:

```
pyenv shell 2.7.11
pip install printtable
```